# Did the entire Cylon race pursue the humans?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, cylon

In BSG (2004), a massive Cylon fleet attacks the 12 colonies and wipes out, to our knowledge, all of humanity except for the fleet led by Galactica and Colonial One, and the Pegasus.

I suppose there are a couple questions here:

- was the Cylon fleet made up of their entire race?
- did they have a homeworld (in addition to the base at the black hole) where the rest were living normal lives?

It seems to me that if they had a homeworld that survived, the entire "the cycle is broken" plot point is actually not fulfilled. Humanity would evolve on a new planet (our Earth), but the Cylon skinjobs could still be around, 150,000 years further evolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They didn't all pursue no, but they didn't have a homeworld exactly (the writers intended there to be but abandoned that idea later on), instead they have "The Colony" - http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/The_Colony

> Since the colony is destroyed in *Daybreak* there is no longer any Cylon "homeworld" out there. And with the loss of the resurrection technology any surviving skinjobs who were out and about in the universe would die off and without the ability to procreate they wouldn't be doing any evolving.